# changing textlabel in form1 using different class

Tags: c#

having a bit of a problem changing the label text when a button is pressed. my code looks like this. i searched a bit in this forum and tried this solution in form1 i have this code.

```
public string info
{
    get
    {
        return label11.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        label11.Text = value;
    }
}
```

in class search i have this

```
public void fighting()
{
    character tom = new character();
    Form1 f = new Form1();
    Random explore = new Random();
    int exploration = explore.Next(0, 3);
    if (character.location == "Forest" || character.location == "Dungeon")
    {

        switch (exploration)
        {
            case 0:
                f.info = "You didnt find anything";
                f.Refresh();
                f.herodamage = exploration.ToString();
                break;
...
```

the button has this

```
public void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Search find = new Search();
    find.fighting();
}
```

what am i doing wrong? everytime i press the button the text wont change but it works because it does change a buttons text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating a new instance of `Form1` you need to get a reference to the already existing instance of this form.

One simple way to do this is to use the `Application.OpenForms` property:

```
character tom = new character();
Form1 f =  Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().FirstOrDefault();
Random explore = new Random();
...
```

Comment: dude you are a lifesaver not only did you help me get this fixed but you also helped me fix a button text one xD

Answer (score 4):

Fighting method is creating a new instance of Form1, different from your UI.

While it is updating label1.Text, it refers to different Form1.

My suggestion is for refactoring of your code to make responsibilities more clear.

Something like

```
var info = find.fighting(); // Where fighting returns string, instead of creating new Form1 and setting value, just return the value.
this.info = info;
```

If you still insist to update UI from search method, which is not correct way to approach this problem, you can pass around Form1 from the parameter.

```
Search find = new Search(this); // Store it as instance of Search class.
find.fighting(); // fighting should never create new instance of Form1 (reason of problem you are facing)
```

Comment: meaning i have to add the whole code to the button? and not into a class? kinda new to programming and learning step by step

Comment: In the current state, it looks like [spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code). It warrants refactoring. To the minimum, your Search class should not know anything about UI.

Comment: yeaahh still trying to get the hang of it.